# Crontab is not running at SSH remote server

Tags: ssh, cron, remote-server

I want to run a bash shell script every 7am every day.
But it didn't work.
This is the commands.

```
00 07 * * * / usr / bin / sh /home/Download/download.sh
```

i have tried running on local device. When I run it on a local device, the crontab works fine, but when I try on a remote server it doesn't run. any solution with this case?

Comment: Why are you putting spaces between all the parts of `/usr/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run /home/Download/download.sh every day at 7am.

First make sure your file is executable:

```
chmod +x /home/Download/download.sh
```

Depending on your machine, the path to `sh` may be different. Check it with `which sh` command. Most times it is at `/bin/sh` so your crontab would look like:

```
0 7 * * * /bin/sh /home/Download/download.sh
```

**But nevertheless I think you don't need `/bin/sh` so your crontab should look like:**

```
0 7 * * * /home/Download/download.sh
```

Comment: The file doesn't need to be executable if you run it use `/bin/sh filename`

Answer (score -1):

One first

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Second

```
chmod +x /home/Download/download.sh
```

and last.

```
0 7 * * * /home/Download/download.sh
```

Comment: First should be chmod, then crontab. Otherwise you have to close crontab again and open again.

Comment: @charly1212 The order doesn't matter. You just need to do the `chmod` before 7am the next day.